# How to power schmitt trigger in LTspice with negative voltage?

Tags: simulation, ltspice, schmitt-trigger

[image]I use CD40106 model in LTspice for schmitt trigger, but the circuit I want to simulate has -5 and 0 V levels, CD40106 only accept positive value for VDD and there is no other param to change the value or may be I am mistaken.

Is there any way I could modify the model to simulate my circuit in -5 and 0V?

Comment: Move your ground?

Comment: @Oldfart cd40106 is self powered.apparantly I can just set for VDD not Gnd through attribute window

Comment: Post your spice netlist or a picture of your schematic

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way I could modify the model to simulate my circuit in -5
>   and 0V?

The circuit in your question shows power rails of -5 volts and 0 volts. That means the actual supply is 5 volts just as in any other more standard circuit of logic chips. In other words it makes absolutely no difference to your simulation.

You can simulate it with standard logic voltage levels and the sim result will be the same except the output will be 5 volts higher. If you need an output that is 5 volts lower (possibly to drive other circuits that are un-shown in your question) then put a 5 volt voltage source in series with the output.

Comment: thank you @Andy-aka, but the actual circuit is way bigger the snapshot I uploaded, I don't want to add extra component because it uses another 6 schmitt triggers. also I wanted to know if its possible to modify or hack the actual CD40106 Model without changing the circuit design.

Comment: Try attaching the ground node to the +5V rail.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Anyone?

Comment: Added a +1 to compensate for the marching moron.